# What happens to the app.config file once I reference the class library

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, app-config, class-library

I have a class library with a app.config file with 4 settings in it. Previously when I tried this (VS2008) as soon as I referenced the library I would not be able to access the config file/application would break, but for some reason it works now. I have referenced the library in 3 applications and I can still access the settings fine but the actual config file is missing.

Does the config file get compiled along with the library as soon as you reference it or what happens to it?

(working in vs2010)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably works because there are defaults in the generated Settings.Designer.cs file. The more important question would be: How can I change my settings?

And that would require copying or merging the relevant XML sections from the library app.config to that of the referencing application.

Comment: If I merge the config files would I be able to change the settings of the library without changing the way the library interacts with the settings ie: Properties.Settings.Default.. or will I need some manager

Comment: ok I'll try that. I just got verification that my libraries config is working because I have default values set. I am still looking at how to merge the two config's.

Answer (score 1):

The config file is renamed; "app" is replaced by the name of your assembly.  So if your app.config is associated with a program, say `Foo.exe`, then in your output folder (eg `bin\debug`) you should have a `Foo.exe.config`.  If your app.config is associated with a class library, say `Bar.dll`, then in the output folder it will be `Foo.dll.config`.

Comment: Also, for any `.settings` file you add to the project, those settings also end up in the `app.config` (not a separate config file).

Comment: I went through all .settings files in the project that is referencing the dll and all .config files and couldn't find the related settings. ps. I know my settings are stored -> lib.dll.config. The lib has default values. The settings are not located in a separate file or the my.exe.config file

Comment: Did you edit the .settings file(s) directly or go through the Settings Designer UI?  The UI generates code in a `.settings.designer.cs` (or `vb`) file, which I believe is where your default values come from.  (I only ask because I made that mistake :)  If you did go through the UI and things still aren't showing up the only thing I can suggest is removing and then recreating the app.config and .settings files.  (Make a backup or at least take screenshots before you do this.)